# Is there support for screen rotation and keyboard/trackpad lock on a yoga 11s in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: screen, 14.04, lenovo, tablet, ideapad

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo yoga 11s. I was wondering if anyone knows if there is/will be support for tablet mode (i.e. screen rotation and input lock for the keyboard and track pad)?

Thanks for any support

Answer (score 0):

There are two projects on the subject of screen rotation:

1) rubo77's [screen-rotate-sh](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/daa262e0229f6e398766#file-rotate-screen-sh) on git, wich is a manual executed script that could be mapped to a key/ combination. It also "should" disable the touchpad with the `xinput enable/deisable "$TouchpadDevice"` code in the script. 
In my case it didn't so I changed the code slightly to execute `synclient touchpadoff=1` instead. One or the other should work.

2) pfp-schneider has created a auto-rotate script collection that is enabling the position sensors of your YOGA and using their output to rotate the screen automatically.
You can find the links to his git-hub on [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1911972&page=24&p=12916659#post12916659) in ubuntuforums.org.
There is a usable step-by-step guide in the same thread in post #241. 
As of today (16APR15) there is small mistake in the raw code of pfp-schneiders program that has to be fixed manually. A "short" explanation by (the smart, cunning, and good-looking) myself how to do it can be found in post #289.

Greetings

Felix